# Clustering data based on case dates

Tags: r, date, cluster-analysis, dplyr

I have a dataset of 20000 individual cases, each with a disease onset date ('onsetdate'). Each case lives in a group home, and I want to cluster cases based on their disease onset date within the home.

So I want to identify the first case that appeared in the home. If another case(s) appeared within 14 days of the first, I want to add them to the same cluster. If another case appeared within 14 days from any other case in the cluster, I want to add them to the same cluster. I would stop adding cases to the cluster once another case was more than 14 days from the last; at that point, a new cluster would form and the process would restart until everyone is sorted. The cluster 'start date' would be the disease onset date of the first case added to the cluster, and the end date would be 14 days after the last case was added to the cluster.

Here's some dummy data:

```
dummy <- data.frame(case = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19), 
                onsetdate  = as.Date(c("2012-08-30", "2012-09-03", "2012-09-09", "2012-09-17", "2012-11-01", "2012-11-05", "2012-11-30", "2012-08-30", "2012-09-03", "2012-10-09", "2012-10-17", "2012-10-30", "2020-12-26", "2020-12-23", "2020-12-30", "2020-12-25", "2021-04-22", "2021-05-03", "2021-05-10")),
                position = c("Resident", "Staff", "Resident", "Staff", "Staff", "Resident", "Resident", "Staff", "Resident", "Staff", "Staff", "Resident", "Resident", "Resident", "Staff", "Resident", "Staff", "Staff", "Resident") , 
                grouphome = c("Group Home 1", "Group Home 1","Group Home 1","Group Home 1","Group Home 1","Group Home 1","Group Home 1","Group Home 1","Group Home 2","Group Home 2","Group Home 2","Group Home 2", "Group Home 3", "Group Home 3","Group Home 3","Group Home 3","Group Home 3","Group Home 3","Group Home 3")
                )
```

And the output would look like this :

```
result <- data.frame(grouphome  = c("Group Home 1", "Group Home 1","Group Home 1","Group Home 2","Group Home 2", "Group Home 3", "Group Home 3"), 
                 clusterNumber = c("1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "1", "2"), 
                 clusterStart = as.Date(c("2012-08-30", "2012-11-01", "2012-11-30", "2012-09-03", "2012-10-09", "2020-12-23", "2021-04-22")),
                 cases = c("5", "2", "1", "1", "3", "4", "3"))
```

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you first want to `group_by` the `grouphome`.

You can also `group_by` the `clusterNumber` which can be determined by looking at differences in `onsetdate` that are greater than 14 days. The use of `cumsum` or cumulative sum will provide a counter for this.

The final `summarise` will take the first date to be the `clusterStart` within a group home cluster, and `cases` will be the number of rows for that cluster.

This assumes that the dates are already sorted chronologically. If that's not the case, you would need to `arrange` first.

**Edit**: To also add two columns for total number of "Resident" and "Staff" for each `clusterNumber`, you can `sum` the `position` for each of these two cases.

```
library(dplyr)

dummy %>%
  group_by(grouphome) %>%
  group_by(clusterNumber = 1 + cumsum(c(0, diff(onsetdate) > 14)), .add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(clusterStart = first(onsetdate),
            cases = n(),
            resident = sum(position == "Resident"),
            staff = sum(position == "Staff"))
```

**Output**

```
  grouphome    clusterNumber clusterStart cases resident staff
  <chr>                <dbl> <date>       <int>    <int> <int>
1 Group Home 1             1 2012-08-30       4        2     2
2 Group Home 1             2 2012-11-01       2        1     1
3 Group Home 1             3 2012-11-30       2        1     1
4 Group Home 2             1 2012-09-03       1        1     0
5 Group Home 2             2 2012-10-09       3        1     2
```

Comment: Thanks so much for responding! When I apply this to my data, it looked like it was only clustering those that were in the same home and had the exact same onset date. When I tried transforming my 'onsetdate' variable to Date format, it started giving me an error after the line  : group_by(clusterNumber = 1 + cumsum(c(0, diff(onsetdate) > 14)), .add = TRUE)

The error is: Error: Problem adding computed columns in `group_by()`.
x Problem with `mutate()` input `clusterNumber`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: Ah nevermind, I wasnt converting to date format properly. It worked now, thank you so much!!!

Comment: Quick question @Ben, could you advice on how I would go about adding a different column for "Staff" vs "Resident", for each cluster?

Comment: Thank you! I think I need to edit it again to give a clearer picture.. Ill reply here when it's ready. I think the problem is more with how I'm 'arranging'

Comment: Actually, that may have solved it! I think I needed to arrange(grouphome,onsetdate) at the outset for them to cluster properly, as you mentioned in your first response!